# DDNS, VPN and Routes

Tags: vpn, routing, nas

My current status is:
Router Asus AC68 that manages DDNS @dyndns and works as OPVN client to perfect-privacy.
I cannot reach my NAS from WAN if the OPVN is up. I can reach other ports though. I even tried to set the NAS as DMZ, but no results.

Is there a way to create a route so that any incoming connection to the NAS via DDNS is rerouted correctly to the LAN IP ?